# Can I use the word vacua when referring to multiple vacuum cleaners?

Tags: word-usage, grammatical-number

The word [vacua](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/vacua/) is a plural of the word vacuum, one definition of which is a vacuum cleaner. While I imagine that the plural vacua is usually reserved for referring to multiple spaces devoid of matter, can it also be used to refer to multiple vacuum cleaners?

Comment: In a humorous way, certainly. If humor is not your intent, there seems little reason to use it. It can be used--it is there in the dictionary for all who look to find, but why? It's virtually nonexistent on ngram, and personally I've never heard it. In a non-joking way, it seems pretentious, or wrong, or contrary--IMHO.

Comment: Is this a more general question, "if X is its own word with plural Xa, but also X is sometimes short for Y, which has plural Ys - should we use Xs or Xa to mean Ys?"  or is it specific to each case? - hoping someone will know

Comment: In vacuum cleaner, vacuum stands for a lack of material and therefore cannot be pluralized. It is the same for "weight loss": if you want to explicitly refer to many losses, you will say "weight losses" and not "weights losses" (unless weights refers to dumbbells).

Comment: @lessthanideal I agree, I think it can be extrapolated to a general question like you posed

Comment: @Graffito, are you saying I can't walk into Walmart and buy two vacuums?

Comment: @StevenLittman: Good luck asking for "two *vacua*" in Walmart, in any case. ;-)

Comment: @Drew--You might get a vacuous stare.

Comment: @StevenLittman - In the sense of "vacuum cleaner", the use of word "vacuum" results from the omission of the noun "cleaner" and "vacuum" became an English word with a very different meaning that its latin origin. We can then consider that its plural form shall follow the English usage (with a final 's') rather than the latin(um->a).

Comment: I assume you can.  However, I've never heard you speak so I don't know that for a fact.

Comment: I'm assuming from this exchange that American's refer to a *vacuum cleaner* as a "vacuum".  Is that correct?  I've never heard it used that way in BrE - to me a vacuum is a space containing nothing, not even air!  (We still often refer to a vacuum cleaner as a "Hoover", from the original manufacturer's name!)

Answer (score 2):

*Vacua* as a plural of *vacuum (cleaner)* would be incorrect.

In **vacuum cleaner**, *cleaner* is the noun, and *vacuum* is an **attributive noun** (a virtual adjective) specifying how the cleaner works, (compare: *whisk broom*, *push broom*, *diesel engine*, etc.).   Note that *vacuum* is singular, as are most adjectives.  Only the noun receives the suffix '**s**'.

Since *vacuum* is short for *vacuum cleaner*, it's pluralized the same as the term it's short for.

Comment: I wonder whether there are similar examples in which an attributive noun abbreviates a whole phrase and takes on a different pluralization as a result.